# Vue v-tabs as template component doesn't render v-item content

Tags: vue.js

I'd like to create a reusable tab component using v-tab and slots in Vue (in TS). Number of current tab is passed as property from url. The problem I have is that content of v-tab-items does not render (only the bar with names). I suppose it's something with slots (when i delete tabs component and use only v-tabs - it works)

Tabs component - tabs.html:

```
<div class="tabs" >
  <v-tabs v-model="tab">
    <slot name="tab-names"></slot>
  </v-tabs>
  <v-tabs-items v-model="tab">
    <slot name="tab-content"></slot>
  </v-tabs-items>
</div>
```

Tabs.vue:

```
@WithRender
@Component
export class Tabs extends Vue {

  @Prop({default: 0})
  tabNumber;

  tab: number = 0;

  mounted(): void {
    if (this.tabNumber) {
        this.tab = parseInt(this.tabNumber, 10);
    }
    this.$watch('tabNumber', this.changeTab);
  }

  changeTab(): void {
    this.tab = this.tabNumber;
  }
}
```

That's how I use it:

```
<tabs :tabNumber="tabNumber">
    <template #tab-names>
        <v-tab> Component1 </v-tab>
        <v-tab> Component2 </v-tab>
    </template>
    <template #tabs-content>
        <v-tab-item >
            <some-component-1/>
        </v-tab-item>
        <v-tab-item>
            <some-component-2/>
        </v-tab-item>
    </template>
</tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code. After fixing it, it seems to be working.
Change `#tabs-content` to `#tab-content`

```html
<slot name="tab-content"></slot>
```

```html
<template #tabs-content>
    <v-tab-item >
      <some-component-1/>
    </v-tab-item>
    <v-tab-item>
      <some-component-2/>
    </v-tab-item>
</template>
```